# (ReactJS + serverless) static served page vs virtual DOM bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, serverless-framework

We are rending serverside ReactJS components with https://github.com/elastic-coders/serverless-webpack

Everything is working great, the component data/markup is rendered out. However the problem happens when we run `serverless webpack serve`

We hit the localhost link and for a split sec we see the app, then it's gone to a white page.

On deeper inspection if we do a View Source, we see ALL the markup, including CSS and JS, everything. However in the Chrome Inspector we only see the app `<div>` and nothing else. It's like once our app script line runs, we replace the static content with the Virtual DOM.

To those are who rendering static pages with React and serverless, how have you overcome this problem?

### View Source

[image]

### Chrome Inspector

[image]

#### Our handler.js file

```
if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
  require('babel-polyfill');
}

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import Home from './src/components/home/HomePage'
const component = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Home />);
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WikiTags</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="author" content="WikiTags.com">
    <meta name="description" content="We rank what people are talking about.">
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days">
    <link href="https://www.wikitags.com/" rel="canonical" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@wikitags">
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@wikitags">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="WikiTags">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="We rank what people are talking about.">
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://admin.wikitags.com/dist/imgs/wikitags-twitter.jpg">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
    <meta property="og:type" content="app">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="WikiTags">
    <meta property="og:title" content="WikiTags | We rank what people are talking about.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://admin.wikitags.com/dist/imgs/wikitags-twitter.jpg">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.wikitags.com/">
    <meta property="og:description" content="We rank what people are talking about.">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://admin.wikitags.com/dist/imgs/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="http://admin.wikitags.com/dist/wikitags.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wikitags-app">
        ${component}
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.wikitags.com/dist/wikitags.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`;

export const home = (event, context, cb) => {
  const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('success');
  });

  prom
    .then(r => cb(null, html))
    .catch(e => cb(e));
};
```

#### Our webpack.serverless.config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './handler.js',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify({
                plugins: [
                    'transform-runtime',
                    'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'
                ],
                presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
            })],
            include: __dirname,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        }]
    }
};
```

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./app";

const root = document.getElementById("wikitags-app");

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, root);
```

### Thoughts

---

It seems at the moment, that we can still use React to build the components, we get the data back from the server and pass that data down as props into the components to set active states, selected states etc etc... serverless then renders the static view.

However, once the user gets the page. We can not add the actual app.bundle.js file because that will destroy the app as seen above. But what we need to do is add raw Javascript or Jquery at the bottom of the static page to handle any logic.

**Does that seem like the correct / only move here?**

Comment: When you view the source, is that markup generated in React, or is that there before React is loaded?

Comment: When I vied the source, that is after React has already loaded. The source is what we should see. However nothing displays, and when inspecting the Elements tab shows nothing inside of the `#wikitags-app` except for a `<div data-reactroot>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out! We removed the `<Router>` from `Root` and just returned `<HomePage />` because we don't need the single-page-app router since we are statically serving all the views.

The Router was breaking the app because it tried to re-route the app after the static content already finished loading.

So instead of this

```
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './home/HomePage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import CatgeoryPage from './category/CatgeoryPage';
import EntityPage from './entity/EntityPage';

export class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route exact={ true } path="/" component={ HomePage }/>
                <Route path="/category" component={ CatgeoryPage }/>
                <Route path="/entity" component={ EntityPage }/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Root;
```

We have this

```
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './home/HomePage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import CatgeoryPage from './category/CategoryPage';
import EntityPage from './entity/EntityPage';

export class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HomePage />
        );
    }
}


export default Root;
```